# Why isn't my server scoreboard team name tag colour working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am now work on a semi-vanilla kit PVP server. Normally, when I set a team colour to blue, it should show blue colour name tag in the TAB (Player list) and above the player. Sadly, I don't know why the name tag colour only works in TAB and the death message. It doesn't work on player name above or in the chat. Please help me fix it.

NOTE: my server is 1.11.2 bukkit version

Comment: If you want us to help you fix the issue, you'll need to show us what to fix.

Answer (score 2):

### You need to disable plugins that alter chat messages / names.

If you have any bukkit plugin for chat tags, colours etc, **vanilla way won't work**. You need to get rid of such a plugin, or disable parts that interfere with those features. Or properly setup colors via group managers and use those plugins to colorize the names.

For example essentials-chat or chatex, or any other that adds prefixes etc.

**Plugins do override vanilla way of showing names.**

Comment: I believe that even without plugins it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

Like [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/298466/162442) says, the chat plugins do interfere. One way to fix this is to get a nickname and take out ~ from it and make sure it says their name.